# how to annotate for every subplot in seaborn facetgrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a facetgrid where columns are my years, x axis are months and Y axis is consumption levels. I have put an horizontal line showing the mean consumption level for every subplot. I also would like to state with an annotate what that mean number is for every column, here yearly data.  Any ideas how to do it?

[image: My facetgrid]

Comment: You should be using `sns.catplot` with `kind='bar'`. As per the documentation, it is not recommended to directly use [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html),

Comment: Asking because I don't know why I should not be using Facetgrid?

Comment: It says right in the FacetGrid documentation in the **Warning** section

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not present any data, I applied your code using the data in the reference.
I created a function to annotate the string and add a horizontal line since the function drawing the horizontal line is unknown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

colors = sns.color_palette()

# load seaborn sample dataset
flights = sns.load_dataset('flights')

def annotate(data, **kws):
    n = data.passengers.mean()
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(.1, .8, "Mean = {:.1f}".format(n), transform=ax.transAxes)
    ax.axhline(y=n, color='red')
    
g2 = sns.catplot(flights, x='month', y='passengers', kind='bar', col='year', col_wrap=4, color=colors[0])
g2.map_dataframe(annotate)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this has been quite useful.

Comment: Your question was unfortunately closed, but I have made a correction to resolve the error and change the color of the bar graph to one color.